# How do I deploy Java servlets to fresh Tomcat server?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

So recently, I've been working with servlets.

I develop on Eclipse and everything in setup is fine and works.

I want to move my application to a server next to me and without having to install Eclipse, etc.

So I installed Tomcat, I took the config files from my Eclipse workspace (my server's folder, server.xml, context.xml, web.xml, etc.) and pasted them into the config folder of Tomcat. The problem is I don't really know how to deploy my app.

I went to `localhost:1515/manager` and from there I tried to deploy my app but it is already there (from the config files I pasted earlier), and it prompts this error when I try to start it:

> "FAIL - Application at context path /someApp could not be started"

So I try to deploy another one but I don't have any XML config files in my eclipse workspace.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you understand how to build a Java web application. If not, there is a bunch of things you need to get right, starting from directory structure. It is not complex, but you should know as it is the basics of all server deployments in Java.
Read documentation [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/)

Once you package your servlets in to a Java web application, follow tomcat's documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/deployer-howto.html)

Sorry to have answered with documentation. But it is really out of scope to SO to write a guide for you.

Comment: This will surely do. Thanks alot !!